# Two versions of Lax-Milgram theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, bilinear-form, riesz-representation-theorem

I'm having some troubles differentiating between two versions of Lax-Milgram theorem, one shown in my class and one that I saw is common on the internet.

Let $H$ be hilbert space, $B$ bilinear form on $H$ which is bounded and coercive.

1. (my class): There is a unique bounded linear operator $S$ with an invertible bounded operator such as $B(Sx,y)=<x,y>$.
2. (interenet): let $\phi$ be a linear functional on $H$. so there is a unique $x \in H$ that maked $\phi(y)=B(y,x)$ for every $y\in H$

hope you could show me at least why the first definition leads to the second. I really tryed and had absolutely no idea (I used riesz' theorem and took $x$ such that for every $y \in H$ $\phi (y)=<y,x>=\overline{<x,y>}=\overline{B(Sx,y)}$, and from here i can't unfortunately lose the conjuget and replace the order of $Sx$ and $y$, which would leed to the solution.

Thanks

Comment: The second is not Lax-Milgram, but the Riesz representation theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem.

Comment: @gerw: you are right of course, i fixed my questions.
It should be $\phi(y)=B(y,x)$ instead of $\phi(y)=<y,x>$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the $B$ in the second formulation does not equal the $B$ in the first one.

Let us proof the second one by using the first one.
Set $\hat B(x,y) = \overline{B(y,x)}$.
By using the first theorem, you find an operator $\hat S$
associated to $\hat B$.
Then,
\begin{equation*}
 \phi(y) = \langle y,x\rangle
 =
 \overline{\langle x, y \rangle}
 =
 \overline{\hat B(\hat S x, y)}
 =
 B(y, \hat S x).
\end{equation*}